# Android Device Monitor is not working

Tags: android, monitor

[image]

can anybody help me to solve this?

Comment: first you have to take look at that log file for the reason . and then ask a question here.

Comment: Jon Skeet even can't help with such little info on issue that you are facing!

Comment: please read the message in dialogue and see the log file.

Comment: can't see that log file sir, how to locate it?

Comment: @PareshMayani Sir thats a good one .

Comment: sorry sir for the short info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update Android SDK Tools
Make sure you have JAVA_HOME in your system environment variables

JAVA_HOME=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_11
1
JAVA_HOME=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_11